# How to extract data

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem in Excel where I need to extract data from a string of text like the one below. The data below are all on separate rows. I'm trying to extract only the data that's in between the slashes into something like `x/y/z/a/b/c` format and ignoring the rest of the data in front. Hopefully this problem can be resolved using vba.

An example:

`s1 167.4/164.2/172.0/165.8/162.5/165.6 
s2 163.6/164.1/167.2/167.1/165.6/167.6 
S#1:0.1682/0.1646/0.1641/0.1653/0.1622/0.1642
S#2:0.1623/0.1621/0.1667/0.1680/0.1667/0.1643
s24=1903/1881/1873/1903/1915/1891 
s25=1872/1858/1904/1879/1854/1868 
SLOT 24:0.2031/0.1991/0.1959/0.1989/0.1987/0.2051
SLOT 25:0.2014/0.2019/0.2014/0.2033/0.2001/0.2017`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I'd want nothing but the number that are in between the slashes, so `s1 167.4/164.2/172.0/165.8/162.5/165.6 ` would become `167.4/164.2/172.0/165.8/162.5/165.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
Public Sub RegExpExample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Variant, arr As Variant
    Dim k As Long
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim Match, Matches

    ' Uses late binding so no need to add references 
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    ' Change this to match your range where your values are
    With Sheet2
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(8, 1))
    End With
    ' Declare RegEx parameters
    With regEx
        .Pattern = "(?:\d*\.)?\d+"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
    End With
    ' Loop through each row
    For Each c In rng
        Set Matches = regEx.Execute(c)
        If Matches.Count > 0 Then
            ReDim arr(1 To Matches.Count)
            k = 1
            For Each Match In Matches
                arr(k) = Match
                k = k + 1
            Next Match
            ' Print back to worksheet
            Range(c.Offset(0, 1), c.Offset(0, UBound(arr))) = arr
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

You'll have to decide how to handle the first column of values that are returned or wait until someone that is better with RegEx puts up an answer

Comment: Great solution Tom!!

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions would be the most robust answer.

A custom VBA function is required and an expression to cover your requirements.

Detailed guide: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

A regex you could use may be: (?:\s|:|=).*

i.e. Find first space or first : or first =, then select everything after.

Comment: I have tried Regex, but in the end I've still got no idea how it works..